# PHPUnit and WebDriver - Where should I add implicitWait() to?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I read some articles, they said implicitWait() works globally. But I'm not sure 
where i should set it.

here is my code:

```
public  function setUp(){
    $this->setHost('10.10.60.95');
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.ABC.com');
    $this->prepareSession();

}

public function testTitle()
{
    $this->url('http://www.ABC.com/');
    $this->assertEquals('ABC', $this->title());
}
```

where should i add implicitWait() to ? the setUp function or the testTitle function?

> $this->timeouts()->implicitWait(10000);

thank you!

**ANSWER:**

As @Arran said, actually i should put this code in setUp() function in most cases ,as it works globally.

```
public  function setUp(){
    $this->setHost('10.10.60.95');
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.ABC.com');
    $this->prepareSession();
    $this->timeouts()->implicitWait(10000);
}
```

if you want to set a special timeout for a test function ,you could add this code in it.

```
public function testTitle()
{
    $this->url('http://www.ABC.com/');
    $this->timeouts()->implicitWait(5000);
    $this->assertEquals('ABC', $this->title());
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking it should be in the setup function, unless you plan to constantly change the value of it.

Comment: thank u @Arran ,i'm gonna write more scripts to test this

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options you can try them. Though not 100% sure of them you can give it a try. Please change them according to your need.

```
1.
// wait for at most 10 seconds until the URL is 'http://example.com/account'.
// check again 500ms after the previous attempt.
$driver->wait(10, 500)->until(function ($driver) {
  return $driver->getCurrentURL() === 'http://example.com/account';
})

2.
$this->_session->timeouts()->implicit_wait(10000); // 1 sec = 1000
```

Comment: thanks, i found  some code samples on github .it seems like this:  public function testTitle()
{
    $this->url('http://www.ABC.com/');$this->timeouts()->implicitWait(10000);
    $this->assertEquals('ABC', $this->title());
}

Comment: If the answer helped you please select it as a answer, it will help others. Thank you !